# Не получается отсортировать таблицу

Tags: javascript

Не получается отсортировать таблицу с помощью [datatables](https://datatables.net). Добавляю все, что требует библиотека, но сортировки не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

```
<table id="table" class="contacts__table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input onchange="selectAllRows(this)" class="contacts__table-checkbox" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow">Title</th>
        <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow">Name</th>
        <th class="contacts__table-sortable contacts__table-sortable_narrow">Surname </th>
        <th class="contacts__table-sortable">Email</th>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th class="contacts__table-sortable">Tags</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) { ?>
        <tr id="tr<?php echo $contact->id ?>" onclick="toggleRowSelected(this)" class="contacts__table-row">
            <td><input class="contacts__table-checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact->title ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact->name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact->surname ?></td>
            <td class="contacts__table-email"><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->email ?></span></td>
            <td><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->note ?></span></td>
            <td><span class="table-overflow"><?php echo $contact->tags ?></span></td>
            <td><label onclick="editContact('tr<?php echo $contact->id ?>')" class="contacts__table-btn contacts__table-btn_edit"></label></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: js код добавьте

Answer (score 0):

Инициализацию делаешь и id соответствует id таблицы?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function (){
        $('#table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```